# Find files which have certain attributes

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, find

I'd like to find all files in the current directory recursively with the following attributes:

- Created within the last 10 days
- Is htm or html file
- Has the following text inside:

  - var iw=document;iw['write']

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be close:

```
 find . -ctime -10 -and \
        \( -iname '*.html' -or -iname '*.htm' \) -print0 | \
    xargs -0 egrep -l "var iw=document;iw\[.*write"
```

Comment: Snap, do you know the presidence of the and/or?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want something like:

```
find . -mtime 10 -and \( -iname '*.html' -or -iname '*.htm' \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -H "var iw=document;iw\[.*write"
```

Comment: Actually thinking about it, I'm not sure of the precedence of the -and and the -or, I'll leave that as an exercise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is a bit superfluous.

```
find . -ctime -10 -and \
    ( -iname '*.html' -or -iname '*.htm' \) \
     -exec fgrep -l "var iw=document;iw['write']" {} +
```